# Having trouble with "string subscript out of range" in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

every time I try and input 't' it returns a "string subscript out of range"

```
while ((y != sequence.length()) && (base != 'u' || base != 't')) {
        base = sequence[y];
        y++;
        if (base == 't')
        {
            //if the sequence is DNA
            while (sequence[y] != sequence[z])
            {
                if (sequence[y] == 't')
                {
                    mRNA_sequence += 'a';
                }
                else if (sequence[y] == 'a')
                {
                    mRNA_sequence += 'u';
                }
                else if (sequence[y] == 'c')
                {
                    mRNA_sequence += 'g';
                }
                else if (sequence[y] == 'g')
                {
                    mRNA_sequence += 'c';
                }
                y++;
            }
            DNA = sequence;
            sequence = mRNA_sequence;
        }
    }
```

if I input 't' it should turn it into an 'a'. it works for the rest.

Comment: You increment `y` **_after_** you check whether you have not reached the end of the string. This means you will always access `sequence[sequence.length()]`, which is Undefined Behaviour. The highest index you should ever access is `sequence.length() - 1`

Answer (score 0):

@Yksisarvinen is correct. The incrementing of `y` is your primary issue. The other reason that it works for `u` and not for `t` is because your code does no processing on any other letter. `if (base == 't')` is the only case provided in your snippet.

You also use `y` as the variable for both the outer-while loop and the inner-while loop. This may be intended behavior, just be cautious. Your inner-while loop will increment `y` and that new, larger value will be the `y` value used in the outer-while loop.

You set `DNA = sequence;` and `sequence = mRNA_sequence;` inside the while loop without breaking it. Keep in mind that the while loop will now have a new 'sequence' to use in the `sequence.length()` call of the while loop. Since I believe your code is meant to have the same length values for DNA and mRNA sequences, you may sneak by, but it is dangerous. Your condition states while `(y != sequence.length())` and if the mRNA_sequence was shorter than the initial sequence, then `y` could be greater than the length and this would still pass your while condition.

Comment: There's three difficult problems in programming. Naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: A wise and classic statement, @Tzalumen.

Comment: It's one of my favorites. A simplified version of the statement from one of the SO founders.